# Is there a UHD/4k version of Praat?

Tags: praat

I have an UHD monitor and the Praat GUI gets squished and messed up because of it (see below)
[image: squishy GUI]

I basically have to change the resolution of my screen to see the buttons properly. Is there a UHD/4k version of Praat out there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even though Praat is a program that deals with linguistics, this question in particular isn't about linguistics or the parts of Praat that deal with linguistics.

Comment: Agreed, this is a question that is better asked at Power User. I presume the OS has some kind of compatibility mode, or else it must not be able to handle the interface of a lot of other software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on poweruser.se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Praat only has versions for different OSs and not cor particular hardware. If it doesn't work in version 6.1.08, then... you could try to figure out how to [change the display routine](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_sources.html). Or mention it to them and it might get on a fix-list.